# Python - For the tuple (number, letter), sort the number first. If the number is the same, sort the letter

Tags: python, sorting

I try to sort a list of tuple: [(1, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (2, 'd'), (2, 'c')]

I want to sort the number first. If the number is the same, then sort the letter. Finally, I want to get [(1, 'a'), (2, 'c'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'b')]

I only know how to sort it according to the number using sort function. Here is my code:

```
lst = [(1, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (2, 'd'), (2, 'c')]
lst.sort(key=lambda i: i[0])

Output: [(1, 'a'), (2, 'd'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'b')]
```

But for the same number term, (2, 'd'), (2, 'c'), how can I sort them to get [(1, a), (2, c), (2, d), (3, b)]?

Comment: @Chris the `key` parameter is useless, isn't it?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco Yes indeed. Thx for pointing out ;)

Comment: By default, python's `sort` and `sorted` functions sort lists of tuples in **lexicographic** order, which is exactly what you want: compare first term first, and in case of a tie, compare next term. By using the `key` optional argument of `sort`, you explicitly told `sort` to only use the first term of the tuple as key for sorting, instead of using the whole tuple. Just call `lst.sort()` without any optional argument and your problem will disappear. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order

Answer (score 1):

You need nothing but the simple `sort` function, with no additional parameters:

```
>>> lst = [(1, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (2, 'd'), (2, 'c')]
>>> lst.sort()
>>> lst
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'c'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'b')]
```

If you don't want to sort the list in-place, just use the `sorted` function:

```
>>> lst = [(1, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (2, 'd'), (2, 'c')]
>>> sorted(lst)
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'c'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'b')]
```